# How to get the value from the sensors in to the vector<ISensor>?

Tags: c++, class, vector, abstract-class, ofstream

I have to make a program using this UML diagram
[image]
to implement the monitoring system of a house.

The value of the generate Temperature, Humidity and Pressure are random. `CreateRoom` will create a text file where the value of the sensors goes, `updateRoom` will add the values to the file, `readRoom` will show on the screen the content of the file and `deleteRoom` will delete the file. I am stuck at `updateRoom` because I don't know how to get the value from the sensors in to the `vector<IRoom> sensor` and then to put it in the file.

This is what I have done so far:

```
//ISensor.h
#ifndef ISensor_H
#define ISensor_H
class ISensor {
public:
    virtual double readSensor() const = 0;
};
#endif

//Temperature.h
#ifndef Temperature_H
#define Temperatur_H
#include<iostream>
#include "ISensor.h"
class Temperature : public ISensor
{
public:
    double readSensor() const {
        return generateTemperature();
    }
    
private:
    double generateTemperature()const {
        int temperature;
        srand((int)time(NULL));
        temperature = -40 + (rand() % 120);
        return temperature;
    }
    
};
#endif 

//Humidity.h
#ifndef Humidity_H
#define Humidity_H
#include <iostream>
#include "ISensor.h"
class Humidity :public ISensor
{
public:
    double readSensor()const {
        return generateHumidity();
    }

private:
    double generateHumidity()const {
        int humidity;
        srand((int)time(NULL));
        humidity = 1 + (rand() % 100);
        return humidity;
    }
};
#endif

//Presure.h
#ifndef Presure_H
#define Presure_H
#include <iostream>
#include "ISensor.h"
class Presure :public ISensor
{
public:
    double readSensor()const {
       return generatePresure();
    }

private:
    double generatePresure()const {
        int presure;
        srand((int)time(0));    
        presure = 300+ (rand() % 800);
        return presure;
    }
};
#endif

//IRoom.h
#ifndef IROOM_H
#define IROOM_H

class IRoom {
public:
    virtual void readRoom() const = 0;
    virtual void createRoom() const = 0;
    virtual void updateRoom() const = 0;
    virtual void deleteRoom() const = 0;
};
#endif // !IROOM_H

//Living.h
#ifndef LIVING_H
#define LIVING_G
#include"IRoom.h"
#include"ISensor.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Living :public IRoom {
public:
    void createRoom() const{
        ofstream Myfile("Living.txt");
    }
    void updateRoom()const {
        ofstream out;
        out.open("Livinf.txt", ios::app);


    }
    void deleteRoom() const{
        remove("Living.txt");
    }
    void readRoom() const{

    }
private:
    vector<ISensor> sensors;

};
#endif
```

Comment: First of all welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: On an unrelated note, only call `srand` *once*, preferably very early in the `main` function. Or better yet, don't use `srand` and `rand` at all, [there's plenty of better functionality](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) in the standard library.

Comment: You iterate through each sensor of your vector<ISensor> and get their value one by one.
Then you write the value to the file. There are plenty of tutorials on how to read/write files in C++, you'll find one easily on internet.

Comment: @MickaëlC.Guimarães can you  show an example? I know how to write in file but i dont know how to iterate them and get the values in vector

Comment: `vector<IRoom>` is wrong, you need a vector of (preferably smart) pointers here, e.g. `vector<std::unique_ptr<IRoom>>`. Same about `vector<ISensor>`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. ok but I still don't know how to get the value from the sensors in the `vector <ISensor>` .

Comment: Presume that you have `vector<ISensor*> sensors` (Note it's better to be smart pointer). Then you may access it by `sensors[0]->readSensor()`. If this is what you need.

Comment: "the value from the sensors" There is a bit of a contradiction here. "The value" is singular, but "the sensors" is plural. Maybe you want to get the value**s** from the sensor**s**? In which case this is a two-step task: (1) go through the sensors, one by one (2) given a sensor, get the value. The first one would be `for (auto& sensor: sensors { ... }` and the second part goes inside the braces.